# How to sort a same column both in asc order and desc order

Tags: sql, oracle11g

With an SQL Query how do we get the output of 2 columns, the first one being a column sorted in asc order and the second one with the order desc and both are same columns.

ex:

```
emp table:
empid
1 
5
9
4
```

The query output should be

```
empid_1   empid_2
1          9
4          5
5          4
9          1
```

What OP tried so far

```
WITH emp1 
     AS (SELECT ROWNUM a, 
                empno 
         FROM   (SELECT empno 
                 FROM   emp 
                 ORDER  BY 1 ASC)), 
     emp2 
     AS (SELECT ROWNUM b, 
                empno 
         FROM   (SELECT empno 
                 FROM   emp 
                 ORDER  BY 1 DESC)) 
SELECT emp1.empno, 
       emp2.empno 
FROM   emp1, 
       emp2 
WHERE  emp1.a = emp2.b;
```

Comment: @visakh: the below is what i have tried
with emp1 as(
select rownum a, empno from (select empno from emp order by 1 asc)
),
emp2 as (
select rownum b, empno from (select empno from emp order by 1 desc)
)
select emp1.empno, emp2.empno from emp1, emp2
where emp1.a = emp2.b;

Comment: Please modify the question instead of commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a common table expression/sub-query factoring clause then you only need to access the table once:

```
with the_data as (
 select empid
      , row_number() over ( order by empid ) as id_asc
      , row_number() over ( order by empid desc ) as id_desc
   from emp
        )
select a.empid as empid_asc
     , d.empid as empid_desc
  from the_data a
  join the_data d
    on a.id_asc = d.id_desc
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with `row_number()` and self join:

```
select e1.empid as empid_1, e2.empid as empid_2
from (select e.*, row_number() over (order by emp_id) as seqnum
      from emp e
     ) e1 join
     (select e.*, row_number() over (order by emp_id desc) as seqnum
      from emp e
     ) e2
     on e1.seqnum = e2.seqnum;
```

EDIT:

You could also do this with `rownum` but it requires an additional `select`:

```
select e1.empid as empid_1, e2.empid as empid_2
from (select e.*, rownum as seqnum
      from (select e.* from emp e order by empid asc) e
     ) e1 join
     (select e.*, rownum as seqnum
      from (select e.* from emp e order by empid desc) e
     ) e2
     on e1.seqnum = e2.seqnum;
```

Comment: +1 for extremely fast, just thought about `rownum` :)

Comment: `rownum` version doesn't work as written - you'd need to nest selects so that `rownum` was applied after the `order by` - currently it is before.