# How to sort a same column both in ASC & DESC order without duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

With an SQL Query how do we get the output of 2 columns, the first one being a column sorted in ASC order and the second one with the order DESC without any duplicate values and both are same columns.

EMP table:

```
EMP_NAME
Megha
Vicky
Neha
Sachin
Neha
```

The query output should be

```
EMP_NAME_ASC    EMP_NAME_DESC
Megha           Vicky
Neha            Sachin
Sachin          Neha
Vicky           Megha
```

I tried below solution 
[How to sort a same column both in asc order and desc order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304240/how-to-sort-a-same-column-both-in-asc-order-and-desc-order?rq=1#)

but that is not giving me distinct values.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a data fallacy to me. How would such a thing be structured?

Comment: This is some weird requirement.

Comment: Feels like something you should do in your backend code, and not in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little modification on Gordon Linoff's answer, you can get distinct names:

```
;WITH
    cte AS
    (
        SELECT      EMP_NAME
                ,   DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY EMP_NAME ASC)       AS RankAsc
                ,   DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY EMP_NAME DESC)      AS RankDesc
                ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_NAME ORDER BY EMP_NAME)
                                                                    AS RowNumber
        FROM        #EMP
    )

SELECT      cte1.EMP_NAME       AS EMP_NAME_ASC
        ,   cte2.EMP_NAME       AS EMP_NAME_DESC
FROM        cte         cte1
INNER JOIN  cte         cte2    ON cte1.RankAsc = cte2.RankDesc
WHERE       cte1.RowNumber = 1
        AND cte2.RowNumber = 1
```

The `ROW_NUMBER` gives a sequential number each time the same name appears. The first time `Neha` appears it will get `1`, the second time it will get `2` and so on. We are interested in the first time each name appears and hence get the distinct names only.

Answer (score 1):

You are two separate lists in columns.  This is not a SQL-ish way to store data -- the rows don't mean anything.  But you can do this, using `row_number()`:

```
select a.name, d.name
from (select name, row_number() over (order by name asc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) a join
     (select name, row_number() over (order by name desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) d 
     on a.seqnum = d.seqnum;
```

Comment: Yeah, it is not the proper way to store the data but this is a weird requirement required for one functionality. I tried your query but it is not giving me an output in distinct values on both columns.